# Implementing A* Search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, a-star, adjacency-matrix

I'm a beginner trying to implement the A* search algorithm for practice and I'm wondering what is the best way of going about it. I have created a graph structure (adjacency matrix) and my plan was to apply the A* to an initial and goal vertex. Also creating the heuristic and improving it as I go along. Question is, can this even work? I have had a look at other implementations and they have done it using different data structures.

Comment: So what the question is? Will your implementation work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you implemented the adjacency matrix.

One critical point of A* is finding a node's neighbors. If you implement the matrix as a simple dense bit field, where you have a 1 for adjacent nodes and a 0 for non-adjacent ones, then this search is quite inefficient because you have to check every node. Although inefficient, this does not prevent you from implementing A*.

If you have a more involved implementation of the adjacency matrix, e.g. as a sparse matrix, which allows you to query the neighbors directly, this will be better suited for A*.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented it as a sparse matrix (sorry I didn't know the exact name for it). Even so, would this still be an inefficient data structure in comparison to alternatives?

Comment: I'm defining the sparse matrix as double graph[][], how would I query the neighbors directly?

Comment: This is not a sparse matrix implementation. It is a sparse matrix stored in a dense matrix representation. See e.g. http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node373.html. With this representation, all neighbors are right next to each other.